# AFrame+Three.js What is more performant between many meshes with few triangles each and few meshes with lots of triangles each?

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, gpu, aframe

I Am using Aframe 1.0.4 with Three.js 111, and I'm currently trying to understand what is more performant between
- Few entities with lots of triangles
- Lots of entities with few triangles each

In this particular case I am trying to understand if it would be better to join the floors of my scene in one big mesh or if it is better to have many different entities but with less triangles.

Generally speaking I think that

- having a lot of entities introduces an overhead due to AFrame (I
  would have to load many gltf-models, entities' components would be
  repeated with their ticks etc) and THREE.js (excessive draw calls on
  the GPU, loading overhead, fetching etc).
- having few big entities would introduce longer loading time (gltf-model), possibly heavier
  raycasting (but i'm not sure about this, please confirm), and maybe a
  more heavy management of the transformations (scale/rotation etc) on
  the THREE.js side

Here are some average numbers in my scene:

- number of entities is about 40 (simple floors, walls, roofs and more
  complex furniture such as sofas, tables, shelves etc), in addition to
  2-10 lights with shadows enabled
- one common shelf has around 25K
- triangles one common floor around 800 triangles

What I would like to know is:

1. What is better, generally speaking, performance-wise, between few entities with lots of triangles and lots of entities with few triangles each ?
2. What is better, talking about simple entities like floors, between 3-4 floors with 1K triangles each, or 1000 floors with 4 triangles each ?
3. Are the assumptions I stated above correct ?

I'm interested about both the THREE.js/GPU(loading time, draw calls, etc) side and the Aframe side (raycasting, components overhead etc.) as well. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely 4 floors with 1k triangles each is better. 1000 individual meshes will kill your rendering performance right off the bat. YOu want to limit your number of draw calls to a few hundred at most. Same goes for physics. Ammo physics uses a bounding volume hierarchy internally to make the collision calculations more efficient so again, for static geoemtry, definitely use large meshes instead of many small meshes.